# changing codeigniters calendar template

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

i am building a web application in code-igniter , i having problem with customizing calendar template. i build a calendar using code-igniter's calendar library

[image]

now i want change template so that day should be listed as follows

---

### 1

### 2

### 3

.. etc

rather than

---

1 2 3

---

4 5 6

---

can any one tell me how it can be done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taken from : http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/calendar.html

By creating a calendar template you have 100% control over the design of your calendar. Each component of your calendar will be placed within a pair of pseudo-variables as shown here:

> $prefs['template'] = '
>
> {table_open}{/table_open}
>
> {heading_row_start}{/heading_row_start}
>
> {heading_previous_cell}<<{/heading_previous_cell}
>   {heading_title_cell}{heading}{/heading_title_cell}
>   {heading_next_cell}>>{/heading_next_cell}
>
> {heading_row_end}{/heading_row_end}
>
> {week_row_start}{/week_row_start}
>   {week_day_cell}{week_day}{/week_day_cell}
>   {week_row_end}{/week_row_end}
>
> {cal_row_start}{/cal_row_start}
>   {cal_cell_start}{/cal_cell_start}
>
> {cal_cell_content}{day}{/cal_cell_content} 
>   {cal_cell_content_today}{day}{/cal_cell_content_today}
>
> {cal_cell_no_content}{day}{/cal_cell_no_content}
>   {cal_cell_no_content_today}{day}{/cal_cell_no_content_today}
>
> {cal_cell_blank} {/cal_cell_blank}
>
> {cal_cell_end}{/cal_cell_end}
>   {cal_row_end}{/cal_row_end}
>
> {table_close}{/table_close} ';
>
> $this->load->library('calendar', $prefs);
>
> echo $this->calendar->generate();

So you have to change your design using different HTML and/or CSS.